# Redmine Notification Emails not sending

Tags: email, redmine

I'm trying to get Redmine to send notification emails, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm following the [directions for email configuration on the Redmine site](https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration), but nothing seems to be working.

My configuration.yml Configurations are:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
      port: 587
      domain: "smtp-relay.gmail.com"
      authentication: :plain
      user_name: "username@domain.org" # this is a G Suite account 
      password: "password"
```

Note that I enabled SMTP relay as described in the Redmine documentation. I've also enabled Less Secure Apps in my Google account.

I've tried:

1. Replacing "default" with "production"
2. Replacing "smtp-relay.gmail.com" with "smtp.gmail.com"
3. Using a totally different G Suite account under a different domain.
4. Using SMTP settings from an Office 365 account that I know work because I use them in Gmail.

Every time, when I go to send a test email from the Redmine interface, I get:

```
An error occurred while sending mail (execution expired)
```

Here's the Redmine info:

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                4.1.1.stable
  Ruby version                   2.6.6-p146 (2020-03-31) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  5.2.4.2
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
  Mailer queue                   ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter
  Mailer delivery                smtp
SCM:
  Git                            2.25.1
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  no plugin installed
```

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-48-generic x86_64) on Linode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting to smtp.gmail.com (as per the configuration guide, use this server in both smtp and domain fields)- You can also try using your domain in the domain field as this might be the one use for the EHLO command in the SMTP transaction. Before connecting, please make sure Less secure apps is enabled and unlock access to the account by clicking on https://accounts.google.com/unlockcaptcha   (wait 1 minute after clicking the link). If the connection is still failed, you should receive a login attempt alert in your Gmail inbox. Can you confirm that?  If you are not receiving this notification then there is a connection issue from the redmine service.

The SMTP relay service (smtp-relay.gmail.com) is more complex, you need to not oly add username and password but configure the service in the Admin console and whitelist the service/app IP address. Also make sure you have selected the correct options to only authenticate registered users or any address within your domain.